# When defining an abstract class, can you force a child to define a property/method defined in a parent interface?

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

Consider the following class definition.

```
public abstract class FooBase : IBar
{
  public int Value {get; set;}
  public string ToString() 
  {
    //Return a string.
  }
}

public interface IBar 
{
  int Value;
  string ToString();
}
```

`FooBase` is a base class that provides implementation of the `IBar` interface.

As an abstract class, `FooBase` cannot be directly instantiated.  Therfore, another class must derive from this class for it to be useful.

Now, consider the scenario where you need an object like `FooBase` that implements the the `IBar` interface, however, for once specific member `IBar` you need the children of `FooBase` to implement it, not `FooBase` itself.

Is there a way to implement/address a member in an abstract class like `FooBase`, derived from `IBar`, in such a way that any child of `FooBase` must implement a single member from `IBar`, rather than relying on the base implementations of `FooBase`?

I assume there isn't because the compiler is telling that declaring a value like `public abstract int Value` is not allowed but I figured it was worth asking and verifying.  But, maybe I'm wrong and if so, is there a proper way to force the child implementation of my base class to implement a member from a parent interface on my base?

Comment: `public abstract int Value { get; set; }`?

Comment: Syntax makes all the difference! Ugh, I'm just not on my A-game today.  I knew this was feasible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> assume there isn't because the compiler is telling that declaring a value like public abstract int Value is not allowed

Of course it is allowed, this compiles perfectly fine:

```
interface IBar
{
    int Foo { get; set; }
    string Blah();
}

abstract class Base: IBar
{
    public abstract int Foo { get; set;}
    public string Blah() => null;
}
```

And now:

```
class Derived: Base
{
     //must implement Foo
}
```

Your code by the way doesn't compile, you can't define fields in an interface.

Answer (score 4):

This compiles just fine:

```
public abstract class FooBase : IBar
{
    public abstract int Value { get; set; }
}

public interface IBar
{
    int Value { get; }
}
```

Any class that derives from `FooBase` must override Value:

```
public class Concrete : FooBase
{
    public override int Value { get; set; }
}
```